# How to bundle multiple ES6 modules into a single ES6 compatible bundle using Rollup

Tags: highcharts, es6-modules, rollup

I'm creating charts with HighCharts v10.x. The HighCharts NPM install includes all necessary ES6 modules.

**The following works just fine.**

At the top of MyChartingModule.js, I import the HighCharts modules like this:

```
import Chart from '../../node_modules/highcharts/es-modules/Core/Chart/Chart';   // 'Chart.js';
import Color from '../../node_modules/highcharts/es-modules/Core/Color/Color';
import LineSeries from '../../node_modules/highcharts/es-modules/Series/Line/LineSeries';
import ColumnSeries from '../../node_modules/highcharts/es-modules/Series/Column/ColumnSeries';
import PieSeries from '../../node_modules/highcharts/es-modules/Series/Pie/PieSeries';
```

This is the script tag:

```
<script type="module" src="../src/js/MyChartingModule.js" defer></script>
```

Now I want to use Rollup v2.70.x to bundle the five scripts into a single bundle so that it can be minified using [rollup-plugin-terser](https://www.npmjs.com/package/rollup-plugin-terser). (I would also like to be able to dynamically load the resulting bundle.)

**This is the approach that I've tried.**

Contents of `rollup/rollup.config.highcharts.js`:

```
import {nodeResolve} from '@rollup/plugin-node-resolve';
// import {terser} from 'rollup-plugin-terser';

export default {
    input: './src/js/chart.bundle.js',
    output: {
        file: './dist/js/chart.esm.js',
        format: 'esm'
    },
    // plugins: [nodeResolve(), terser()]
    plugins: [nodeResolve()]

};
```

Contents of `chart.bundle.js`:

```
import Chart from '../../node_modules/highcharts/es-modules/Core/Chart/Chart';   // 'Chart.js';
import Color from '../../node_modules/highcharts/es-modules/Core/Color/Color';
import LineSeries from '../../node_modules/highcharts/es-modules/Series/Line/LineSeries';
import ColumnSeries from '../../node_modules/highcharts/es-modules/Series/Column/ColumnSeries';
import PieSeries from '../../node_modules/highcharts/es-modules/Series/Pie/PieSeries';
```

NPM script

```
"build:charts": "rollup --config rollup/rollup.config.highcharts.js",
```

Result of running script:

```
> rollup --config rollup/rollup.config.highcharts.js

loaded rollup/rollup.config.highcharts.js with warnings
(!) Unused external imports
terser imported from external module "rollup-plugin-terser" but never used in "rollup/rollup.config.highcharts.js"

./src/js/chart.bundle.js → ./dist/js/chart.esm.js...
(!) `this` has been rewritten to `undefined`
https://rollupjs.org/guide/en/#error-this-is-undefined
node_modules/highcharts/es-modules/Series/Pie/PieSeries.js
 9:  * */
10: 'use strict';
11: var __extends = (this && this.__extends) || (function () {
                     ^
12:     var extendStatics = function (d, b) {
13:         extendStatics = Object.setPrototypeOf ||
...and 1 other occurrence
node_modules/highcharts/es-modules/Series/Line/LineSeries.js
 9:  * */
10: 'use strict';
11: var __extends = (this && this.__extends) || (function () {
                     ^
12:     var extendStatics = function (d, b) {
13:         extendStatics = Object.setPrototypeOf ||
...and 1 other occurrence
node_modules/highcharts/es-modules/Series/Column/ColumnSeries.js
 9:  * */
10: 'use strict';
11: var __extends = (this && this.__extends) || (function () {
                     ^
12:     var extendStatics = function (d, b) {
13:         extendStatics = Object.setPrototypeOf ||
...and 1 other occurrence

...and 3 other files
created ./dist/js/chart.esm.js in 1s
```

Replace the imports in `MyChartingModule.js` with a single import:

```
import {Chart, Color, LineSeries, ColumnSeries, PieSeries} from '../../dist/js/chart.esm';
```

After reloading the page, the Chrome console shows this error:

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: The requested module '../../dist/js/chart.esm' does not provide an export named 'Chart'
```

**Why did the resulting bundle drop the `Chart` export?** And I assume the other exports.

**What changes do I need to make to fix the problem?**

Comment: Hi, have you checked this [docs](https://github.com/highcharts/highcharts#load-highcharts-from-the-cdn-as-ecmascript-modules) about load Highcharts as ES modules?

Comment: https://unpkg.com/browse/highcharts@10.2.0/es-modules/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For Rollup to successfully bundle, you need to add the exports to your input script, `chart.bundle.js`:

```
import Highcharts from '../../node_modules/highcharts/es-modules/Core/Globals.js';
import SVGRenderer from '../../node_modules/highcharts/es-modules/Core/Renderer/SVG/SVGRenderer.js';
import Chart from '../../node_modules/highcharts/es-modules/Core/Chart/Chart';   // 'Chart.js';
import Color from '../../node_modules/highcharts/es-modules/Core/Color/Color';
import LineSeries from '../../node_modules/highcharts/es-modules/Series/Line/LineSeries';
import ColumnSeries from '../../node_modules/highcharts/es-modules/Series/Column/ColumnSeries';
import PieSeries from '../../node_modules/highcharts/es-modules/Series/Pie/PieSeries';

const exports = Highcharts;

exports.Renderer = SVGRenderer;
exports.SVGRenderer = SVGRenderer;
exports.Chart = Chart;
exports.chart = Chart.chart;
exports.Color = Color;
exports.LineSeries = LineSeries;
exports.ColumnSeries = ColumnSeries;
exports.PieSeries = PieSeries;
export default exports;
```

Though it is an example for when using Gulp, here is a useful reference, [Creating custom Highcharts files](https://www.highcharts.com/docs/getting-started/how-to-create-custom-highcharts-files)